# Build VSTS com erro (missing an assembly reference)

Tags: c#

Alguém já teve este erro ao executar o build no VSTS ?

Tenho um projeto `C#`, que roda localmente e consigo publicar no servidor. tentei efetuar o check-in do projeto no VSTS, para automatizar o build e ocorre sempre o erro abaixo...

```
2018-05-02T14:13:58.6494940Z ##[error]XXXX.XXXX\XXXX\Entities\xxxxx.cs(3,45): Error CS0234: **The type or namespace name 'Schema' does not exist in the namespace 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations' (are you missing an assembly reference?)**
2018-05-02T14:13:58.6502791Z XXXX\Entities\xxxx.cs(3,45): **error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Schema' does not exist in the namespace 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations' (are you missing an assembly reference?)** [D:\a\3\s\XXXX.XXXXX\XXX.XXXXX.csproj]
```

O build passa pelo Nuget restore normalmente, só mesmo na hora do build ele dá este erro em diversos arquivos.

Comment: Qual _agent_ está usando para realizar a build?

Comment: Ja tentei o Hosted e o Hosted 2017, a aplicação foi desenvolvida no VS2015, já tentei usar todas as configurações possíveis, efetuando o Clean, restaurando pacotes, nada, vou tentar recriar uma solução vazia e ir adicionando os arquivos aos poucos, pra ver o que dá ...

Comment: Como estão as referencias das dlls no seu csproj? Estão com caminho relativo? são pacotes nuget?

Answer (score 2):

Boa noite,

Segue abaixo alguns passos:

1) Verificar no *.csproj se a referência não está com um diretório fixo na sua máquina;

2) Verificar se você está recuperando os pacotes do nugget no seu build;

Caso os passos acima não resolva o problema, é possível instalar o agente na sua máquina local e efetuar um debug para tentar encontrar o problema.

Att,

Edson José Martins